# Somfony 2 set header content mime-types automatically

Tags: symfony, mime-types

I have a question about Symfony 2.
I would like to  know how if there is a function implemented in Symfony 2 who return the content mime-type ?

Why mime-type cause trouble ? i have some file and i dont want everyone access to it then i made a methode who check if you  have the right to access to  this ressource.

```
chdir("Directory/".$nameoftheressource);
$file = file_get_contents($nameoftheressource);/**/
$namearray=explode(".", $nameoftheressource);
$extension=end($namearray);

$returnFile= new Response();
$returnFile->setContent($file);
if($extension == "css" )
{ $returnFile->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/css');
  return $returnFile;}
```

Thanks to you xabbuh this is near to work perfectly  and as u said saved lot of time
now the code look like

EDIT

```
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;
    //some code
    return new BinaryFileResponse('/Directory/'.$nameoftheressource);
```

But now it does display the css file but propose me to download it bt i would like to display it as a css normal css file

Comment: Automatic mime type detection might not work for every content type (CSS files being one of them which will probably be detected as text/pain or something similar). In those cases you would have to set the `Content-Type` header yourself.

Comment: Look like it working well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save a lot of code by using the [BinaryFileResponse class](http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/BinaryFileResponse.html) which among other things automatically adds the right content type header.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to serve a protected CSS file. In this case, you can use the following code and protect the access to this controller using the Symfony Security system:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/css/app.css", name="css")
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
     */
    public function renderCss()
    {
        $cssFilePath = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/data/app.css';
        $cssContent = file_get_contents($cssFilePath);

        return Response($cssContent, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'text/css'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it was like the old solution ( i didnt show how i check if the user have the right to  access at the file ) there is some other type of ressources as  png, jpeg, svg, js, but with this kind  of solution i have to write every Content-Type for each type of ressources